# pyModbusTCP: read/write_single_coil - what is the bit address in my case?

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbustcp

I am exploring the option to communicate with a device using the pyModbusTCP module and python. The vendor has sent me the Communication Protocol layout, but I don't understand how to relate the information from the manual and the input that pyModbusTCP wants.

I do not have the device yet and I am also new to Modbus, having read through Wikipedia and some other articles mostly.

Here is an excerpt from the manual (apologies, I do not know how to insert tables):

```
+------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+
|    Modbus address      |      Bit      |    Description           |
+------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+
|    2                   |      0        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      1        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      2        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      3        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      4        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      5        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      6        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      7        |    Binary, some function |
+------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+
|    104                 |      0        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      1        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      2        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      3        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      4        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      5        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      6        |    Binary, some function |
|                        |      7        |    Binary, some function |
+------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+
|    112                 |               |    Current level, 0-200  |
+------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

The manual also explains that the MODBUS functions 0x03, 0x01, 0x06, 0x10, and 0x05 are supported.

My plan is to use this function from pyModbusTCP to read the coils:
**read_coils(bit_addr, bit_nb=1)** and **write_single_coil(bit_addr, bit_value)**.

```
Modbus function READ_COILS (0x01)
Parameters: 
bit_addr (int) – bit address (0 to 65535)
bit_nb (int) – number of bits to read (1 to 2000)
Returns:    
bits list or None if error

Return type:    
list of bool or None
```

My questions to you - kind reader - are the following:

1. How would one implement to read i.e. the "Modbus address"=104 "Bit"=3 for example? Am I missing something basic? I would like to avoid having to write a custom communication program but rely on pyModbusTCP if possible. The read bits example from pyModbusTCP is here: https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/read_bit.html
2. How would one implement to *write* i.e. the "Modbus address"=2 "Bit"=6 for example? Is the following correct:

```
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
import time
SERVER_HOST = "localhost"
SERVER_PORT = 502
c = ModbusClient()
c.host(SERVER_HOST)
c.port(SERVER_PORT)

addr = 2
while True:
    # if open() is ok, write coils (modbus function 0x01)
    if c.is_open():
        is_ok = c.write_single_coil(addr, 0) # bit 0
        time.sleep(0.5)
        is_ok = c.write_single_coil(addr, 0) # bit 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
        is_ok = c.write_single_coil(addr, 0) # bit 2
        time.sleep(0.5)
        is_ok = c.write_single_coil(addr, 0) # bit 3
        time.sleep(0.5)
        is_ok = c.write_single_coil(addr, 0) # bit 4
        time.sleep(0.5)
        is_ok = c.write_single_coil(addr, 0) # bit 5
        time.sleep(0.5)
        is_ok = c.write_single_coil(addr, 1) # bit 6 <<--
        time.sleep(0.5)
        is_ok = c.write_single_coil(addr, 0) # bit 7
        time.sleep(0.5)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Many thanks for any insights and help.